# two different controllor having two different MultipartFile size in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartfile

I need to upload two kinds of files for one the maximum file size is 10MB and for another file size is 50KB.
so I created an environment variable in the application.properties file there I gave the value as 1KB.
now my question is how to change the file size 1KB to 50KB and 10MB at runtime.
I tried to do it in many ways but it's now working for me.
[Environment variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrqQD.png)

applicationl.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/import_csv_mysql
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Manoj2@@@
spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#fileSize=2KB
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=${fileSize}
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=${fileSize}
```

In this FileSizeConfiguration class I'm getting environment variable value and store in the "size" and created a setter.

```
@Configuration

public class FileSizeConfiguration {
    @Value("${fileSize}")
    private String size;

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.parse(size));
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.parse(size));
        System.out.println(size);
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

controller

```
    @RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private FileSizeConfiguration fileSizeConfiguration;
    @GetMapping("users/add")
    private void addUsers(@RequestParam("File")MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        //....
    }
    @GetMapping("file/add")
    private void addFile(@RequestParam("File")MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        //....
    }
    //using this method changing the file size 
    @PostMapping("filesize/change")
    private void changeSize(@RequestParam String size){
        fileSizeConfiguration.setSize(size);
    }
}
```

here before calling the users/add i will set the file size to 50KB using the changefilesize/change, and for file/add i will change the file size to 10MB. but it's not working as i thought. always it giving the error " exceeds the configured maximum (1024) 1KB".

[postman screenshot for adding file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nucCD.png)

[postman screenshot for changing file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ln79.png)

I will always change the filesize and will import the file, even though I getting the same error, I don't know why the maximum file size is not changing. but while printing the size value I'm getting the new value what i changed.